# Trying to get Uri for Camera capture in Android but app returning to main screen after image capture

Tags: java, android

Code I was using before;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = Helper.getOutputMediaFileUri(Helper.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(
                        intent,
                        ApplicationConstants.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This would cause an error on apps below API 24 `ClipData.item.getUri`

So I changed the method to this;

```
btncamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Helper.getOutputMediaFileUri(Helper.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
                } else {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/photoTemp.jpg");

                    Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            intent,
                            ApplicationConstants.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now the camera loads, but when I take a picture, it just goes back to the first screen again, I can't think why it's not moving to the page which shows you the captured image.

For reference;

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == ApplicationConstants.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FaceView.this, HandleImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("Mode", this.getMode());
                intent.putExtra("Uri", fileUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (requestCode == ApplicationConstants.RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE
                    && data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(FaceView.this, HandleImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("Mode", this.getMode());
                intent.putExtra("Uri", uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the `onClick()` `if` statement, is the code block correct? You put some data in the `intent` but you don't call `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: I do, if you can see towards the bottom of that statement;
`startActivityForResult(intent,             ApplicationConstants.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: yes, but that's in a separate code block - the `else` block. In other words the `if` block doesn't access the `else` block if the condition is true

Comment: I understand but this is testing on API higher than N so it skips the first part as my phone is API 29 and it still doesn't work.